# IE11 input type="file" dialog doesn't open

Tags: html, file, input, dialog, internet-explorer-11

the following problem occurs in IE11, but not in FF and not in Chrome. The problem is that the file dialog will **not** appear after hitting the browse button.

```html
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
    <input type="file" class="upload" name="staticfile" id="staticFile" accept=".csv" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" />
  </button>
</form>
```

However, if I remove the button container, it'll work. Any idea why that is and how to fix it in IE11?

```html
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
    <input type="file" class="upload" name="staticfile" id="staticFile" accept=".csv" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

The purpose of the code is to have a upload button with an icon, not showing the selected file name, and directly submitting the selected file without a seperate "and now upload the selected file" button.

Thanks a lot for your help

Juergen

Comment: You rather should hide the file input and trigger it with javascript on button click.

Comment: But it's working fine with all browsers except IE11. So what is the problem with it?

Comment: Doesn't work in my browser. FF 43.0.4

Comment: true. It is working with FF in the full app though. hmm ..

Comment: my fault: replace <button> with <span> and it's working fine.

Comment: A file `input` in `button` is invalid HTML. You can not expect consistent results based on invalid HTML.